# FB Graph subscription iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Me and Graph: a combination made in hell.
Consider the following:

In order to establish a FB subscription I have this method:

```
-(void)subscribeToFacebook{
    (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) ? NSLog(@"is open") : NSLog(@"is closed");

    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"page", @"object",
                            @"http://www.example.com/fbcallback.php", @"callback_url",
                            @"about, picture", @"fields",
                            @"ItsMeAlright", @"verify_token",
                            nil
                            ];
    /* make the API call */
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/{app-id}/subscriptions"
                                 parameters:params
                                 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                          completionHandler:^(
                                              FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error
                                              ) {
                              /* handle the result */
                               NSLog(@"error= %@",error);
                          }];
    }
```

that I virtually literally copied from the FB manual.

On http://www.example.com/fbcallback.php I have this code:

```
<?php
$hub_mode = $_GET['hub_mode'];
$hub_challenge = $_GET['hub_challenge'];
$hub_verify_token = $_GET['hub_verify_token'];
if ($hub_verify_token =='ItsMeAlright')
{
    echo $hub_challenge;
}
//and here i am planning to add some logic.
?>
```

Unfortunately, when iOS runs my method, it logs the following error:

> Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x7e921970
>   {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain
>   Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo=0x7d7a21a0
>   {NSUnderlyingError=0x7d4388c0 "unsupported URL",
>   NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL},
>   com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=200,
>   com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=,
>   expirationDate: 2015-04-07 09:12:48 +0000, refreshDate: 2015-02-07
>   08:57:41 +0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0000-12-30 00:00:00 +0000,
>   permissions:(
>       "public_profile",
>       email,
>       "user_friends" )>}

What is that all about? The error actually suggests that this is rather an iOS thing. I'm confused. Hope you are not.

Comment: Or should I replace "{app-id}" with my App ID?

Comment: Is this question just too plain stupid? Or do you guys and gals actually celebrate the weekend?

Comment: Yes, you need to replace it with your app id

Comment: OK, thanks. It took me another step further (now I get a "(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token.", but I see that is well documented. I thought the "{app-id}" was some kind of a variable, since my app ID is clearly stated in the error response. Why would I have to include it, when it is obviously known already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All official Facebook documentation uses `{user-id}`,`{app-id}` as placeholders.

If you don't want to supply the app id and let the API determine it use `app`. So,

`[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/app/subscriptions"`

When testing in future, it's best to start with just the API alone in a bare bones setup e.g. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ so you can ensure the API calls are working before doing platform specific implementations.

Comment: Thanks, that was useful to know. I'm really struggling with Graph. If you could also shortcut me on how to pass the Facebook Access Token in this subscription call, I would be EXTREMELY grateful. (I know how to get the token, no clue though how to return it to FB to get the subscription working)